# How do i remove the table attribute in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql called advertisements, in which there is an entity called position , now while creating the table i have defined the position entity as unique so that i don't get the duplicated entry into the table, now i want to remove that Unique attribute from the table entity Position in the table advertisement.

what is the mysql syntax for this?

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisements` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`pos` smallint NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Above is the Code, can someone please make a syntax for me drop that Unique Attribute attached to the pos entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unique index have some name, use:

```
 ALTER TABLE `advertisements` DROP INDEX `index_name_on_position`
```

Use:

```
 SHOW INDEXES IN advertisements
```

To obtain its name.

Comment: i am sorry to say but i am a newbie and i am not catching your point exactly, i am unsure of what you mean by index_name_on_postion , i have edited my post and put on the code there, can you create a mysql code for me to alter the table. thanks

Comment: I mean, that if you created index this way: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mylovelyindex ON advertisements(position (10));
A name for your 'index_name_on_position' will be 'mylovelyindex'